# Почему не работает второй url в background-image?

Tags: css, изображения

В `background-image` не работает второй `url` - `url("Images/color.jpg")`.

Путь к файлу правильный. В чем может быть причина?

```css
    *{
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    
    .header{
     width: 100%;
     height: 80px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     background-image: url("images/Logo-Blog_76.png"), url("Images/color.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: 1600px 160px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">
     <title>mysite</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="header">
     
             
     </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Не работает именно 2ой color.jpg. Подразумевается, что он должен быть под Logo-Blog_76.png.

Comment: регистр "images" и "Images", правильные пути ?

Comment: да, я пробовал по всякому Logo-Blog_76.png работает без проблем

Answer (score 0):

Уберите background-size: 1600px 160px; Все появится.

Comment: Убрал и заработало!

Comment: Лучший вариант на сайте не написать что работает а отметить как подходящее решение, на против ответа ;)

Comment: опишите пожалуйста поподробнее, как это сделать)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer т.е. напротив моего ответа нужно отмечать а не на своем.

Comment: нажмите галочку слева от отета